# Put section on the left of text instead of above

Tags: sectioning, positioning, sections-paragraphs

How can I get section headers on the left of the text, so I get something like

```
My Section Header       Some text
                        More test
                        [...]

Another Section Header  Some text
                        More test
                        [...]
```

## Edit

I have tried using `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` with

```
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\raggedright}{}{0em}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\titlespacing*{\section}{2cm}{0cm}{0cm} % {command}{left}{before}{after}[right]
```

but the vertical spacing is inconsistent in each section.

Besides, the page sizing is very difficult to handle when I set the margin with either `usepackage{fullpage}` or `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`.

I could, instead, use a table, but I really want to use sections; however, I don't think I should place the sections in the margins, since there is so many problems doing so.

Comment: Thhis requires a large inner margon and/or comparatively short section titles. You can do that with the `| titlesec` package.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using titlesec :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\leftskip=3cm

\titlespacing{\section}{-2cm}{1cm}{-.8cm}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\rule{\paperwidth}{1mm}\\[-12pt]}
\begin{document}

\section{Test1}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Test2}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]